# How passing argument in IIFE works? and why i can be executed only once

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how IIFE pass the argument and why it can't be executed twice

As we can see from the code below

```js
(function(param){
 console.log(param)
})("foobar")
```

Question 1

If the Yellow Parentheses refer to each other
shouldn't it be part of yellow parentheses arguments (I'm referring to the built-in function array for the argument passed)
since the yellow parentheses is also a function(I believe)
instead, it got passed to the inner function

[image]

Question 2

and is there any explanation why it could be only run once (I know Immediately-invoked Function Expression pretty self-explanatory) but i want to know the reason why it could be only called once

I Tried to do this

```js
(function(param){
 console.log(param)
})("foobar")

//I tried to invoke it here
("Invoked2")
//I expected the second console log to display Invoked2 instead i got is not a function and there's no semicolon
```

I have just started learning javascript I'm sorry if it sounds stupid if you need additional information to clear things up, just comment i will respond as soon as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: It passes the argument exactly how _any_ function invocation does. The yellow parentheses are just an artefact of some plugin you're using, they don't tell you anything special. And `("Invoked2")` doesn't work because the IIFE doesn't return a function to be called; if it did, that _would_ work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe — The yellow parentheses are somewhere that the JS compiler expects to fund an expression, so the function keyword creates a function expression. Without them it would be a function declaration and following that with `(...)` would throw an exception.

Comment: @Quentin I'm not sure what you're trying to say. My point is that _both_ pairs being yellow is just because that colour is now freed up because the previous set is closed, it's not telling the OP anything about the sytnax or semantics.

Comment: @jonrsharpe — Ah, I misinterpreted your meaning to be about the presence of the parentheses rather than their colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
var x = (function(param){
   console.log(param)
});

x("foobar");
```

First you define a function, then you assign it to `x`, then you call the function in `x` with an argument.

When you use an IIFE, you skip the step where you assign to `x` and mash the "define a function" together with the "call a function" parts.

You can only call it once because you skipped the assigning to `x` to there is nowhere to get access to the function to call it again.

---

Just adding extra `("value")` is the same as doing:

```
var y = x("foobar");
y("value");
```

You're trying to call the **return value** of `x` as a function.

Your IIFE doesn't have a return statement so it returns `undefined`. Since `undefined` is not a function you get an error.

Now you could make it a named function expression and return the result:

```js
(function i_have_a_name(param) {
  console.log(param);
  return i_have_a_name;
})("foobar")("value")
```

… but this gets increasingly pointless.

---

The primary benefit of an IIFE is that it lets you run some code which can use variables inside it without polluting the scope the function runs in with those extra variables.

Thanks to `let` and `const` allowing variables to be defined at the *block* level (which is very well supported) and ES6 modules providing more convenient encapsulation for chunks of code, IIFEs are largely irrelevant for modern JS.

---

The parentheses around the function expression cause the JS compiled to treat it as a function expression and not a function declaration. Following a function declaration with `(...)` would cause an exception.

There's no relationship between the two sets of parentheses that are highlighted in yellow. That is just your IDE showing that they have the same level of nesting.

Comment: I see as @jonrsharpe said the outer () doesn't have any meaning right?

Comment: @Vaness — No, that's incorrect as my response to him said.

Comment: `(function(param){
 console.log(param)
})("foobar")("value")` so if i'm doing it like this i'm basically use ("foobar") as function and ("value") as the argument , which doesn't work because ("foobar") parentheses 
is not a function and  it's actually a value from function(param) am i right ? @Quentin

Comment: if you wouldn't mind answering i would like to ask for additional information to get a better understanding of function.  `(function(param) {codehere} (); )` per my understanding so far () after the func express is what execute it so does it treat  whole `function(param) {codehere}` as identifier? if not how can `()` identify the anonym function? @Quentin

Comment: No, you’re trying to treat the result of evaluating `(function(param){  console.log(param) })("foobar")` as a function.

Comment: `does it treat whole function(param) {codehere} as identifier?` — No, identifiers are tokens used to name things or find things by name like variables and properties in object literals.

Comment: `if not how can () identify the anonym function?` is doesn’t *identify* anything. The expression to the left of it evaluates as a function.

Comment: i.e if i type `var x = k();` or `9()` it run k and 9(without declaring var) as a function and referring to my case `(//functionex)()`  the latter execute (//functionex) is it correct? so If i type anything and put () after.it will run as function. ( I'm sorry if its not clear enough what I am trying to ask here how the empty parentheses target the parentheses with an expression inside it)

Comment: Expressions create values. Things to the right hand side of that value do things with it. `1 + 2` takes the value 1 and the `+` operator adds to it. You could replace `1` with `function_that_returns_1()`. In an IIFE the expression in the parentheses resolves to a value that is a function. Putting `()` to the right hand side of a function calls the function